# how to properly check if a string is in txt file

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, txt

I'm writing a program that manages a library. This part of the program is where you borrow a book, but only if it's in the library, so I check if the book is in the library but it always comes back negative even if the string is in the library txt file.

```java
FileReader fileInvc = new FileReader("library.txt");
        BufferedReader readervc = new BufferedReader(fileInvc);
        String linevc;
        String readvc=readervc.readLine();
        if((linevc = readvc) != null) {
            if((linevc.contains(book))) {
                // what happens after weve found out that the book is the library txt file
            }else{
                System.out.println("libray does not contain this book");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("error retry");
        }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does it write you "library does not contain this book"?

Comment: What does this question have to do with Notepad++?

Comment: Do you know what a loop is? Your current code is only looking at the first line of the text file. You have to use a loop to read the rest of the text file too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just checking the first line. If you want to check if the book exists anywhere in the file, you need to continue reading it until you find the book or until you reach the end of the file:

```java
private static boolean isInFile(String book) {
    try (FileReader fileInvc = new FileReader("library.txt");
         BufferedReader readervc = new BufferedReader(fileInvc)) {
         String readvc = readervc.readLine();
         while (readvc != null) {
             if (readvc.contains(book)) {
                 return true;
             }
             readvc = readervc.readLine();
         }
         return false; 
    }
}
```

Note that using [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) could easier than using a reader:

```java
private static boolean isInFile(String book) {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get("library.txt")).anyMatch(l -> l.contains(book));
}
```

Comment: The question is probably homework for someone learning to program. Next time, guide him to the answer instead of giving it in full